# Sizing nodes according to input weighting not connectivity

Tags: gephi

I am trying to use Gephi to help graph interview analysis results.  The relationship map is only used to describe conventional connections and life cycles.  What I would like to do is to size the nodes based on the number of interview responses that talk about the node, not the number of connections it has or the weighting of those connections.  Can Gephi do this and if so, how do I do it please?

I have loaded in node weightings and can see this as part of node labels, but haven't been able to find a way of this having an effect on node size.

Many thanks

Comment: PS I have used the diamond size icon under ranking to no avail

Comment: Thanks I have found the issue with the strings - at first there was no option to change the input so I had to do this in the base Excel spreadsheet.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Data input field - change input format to integer

Answer (score 0):

You can load the graph in gexf format adding a float attribute and add this attribute to ALL the nodes. It would like something like:

```
...
            
                
                    
                                        
                    
...
```

Once imported in Gephi, just go to the appearance tab and it will appear as one more attribute in "ranking" drop-down list.

If any problem with gefx format, let me know and I'll will share a whole example (just trying to remain short :-)

Regards